# Extract SQL Where conditions in C# array

Tags: c#, sql, split

Is this possible to do?

I have a SQL query as follows.

`Select * from Table1 where Site = 'Location 1' and AHU='1'`

I need to extract only the where conditions to c# array for example

only

> Site = 'Location 1'
> AHU = '1'

Is it possible to this in c#. Please help.

Comment: Anything is possible... what have you tried.  Might the individual predicates be separated by more than just “and”.  May they be nested within parentheses, have sub-queries or complex expressions with functions/special keywords.

Comment: The allowed combination of predicates within a where clause is rather complex.  If you need full fidelity you will probably need an actual parser and to know what particular variant of SQL is being used.  If you just need simple expressions you can use a simple split string combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can be realized with regular expressions and SQLParser.

With SQLParser 'Carbunql' you can do something like this.

```cs
using Carbunql;

var sq = new SelectQuery("Select * from Table1 where Site = 'Location 1' and AHU='1'");

Console.WriteLine(sq.WhereClause!.ToOneLineCommand().CommandText);

var cnd = sq.WhereClause!.Condition;
cnd.GetTokens().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("  " + x.Text);
});
```

results

```
where Site = 'Location 1' and AHU = '1'
  Site
  =
  'Location 1'
  and
  AHU
  =
  '1'
```

https://github.com/mk3008/Carbunql